# Get number before selected word form string using preg_match function in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to get the mm and inches values from the following string using `preg_match`.

```
$string = "Gold 5.0mm Rolo Chain 18" In";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you tried something? What doesn't work?

Comment: simple @Toto want a value of 'mm' and 'In' from string. means that want to get number before word of 'mm' and 'In' using preg_match.

Comment: Thank to all for edit corrections.

Comment: Does `$string = "Gold 5.0mm Rolo Chain 18" In";` or `$string = "Gold 5.0mm Rolo Chain 18 In";`

Comment: possible in both conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex:** `([\d\.]+)(?:mm|\")`

`([\d\.]+)(?:mm|\")` This will match digits , `.` before `mm` and `"`.

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/779542)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='Gold 5.0mm Rolo Chain 18" In';
preg_match_all("/([\d\.]+)(?:mm|\")/", $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);// its 1 index will return your desired result
```

**Or:**

**Regex:** `/[\d\.]+(?=mm|\")/`

`[\d\.]+(?=mm|\")` match digits , `.` and positively look ahead for `mm` and `"`

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/779543)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='Gold 5.0mm Rolo Chain 18" In';
preg_match_all("/[\d\.]+(?=mm|\")/", $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: @RP You can use second solution and use `$matches[0]`

Comment: thanks for help me again @sahil if I have string like "Gold 5.0mm Rolo Chain 18 In" how can I get "In" number from string?

Comment: @RP try this one for that `/[\d\.]+(?=mm|\"|\s* In)/i` check this https://eval.in/779544

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/847b66e267e4d0983471eb1bab665abac8430023 get some error

Comment: @RP try this https://eval.in/779556, In that code some thing was missing

Comment: Just omitting preg_match... This magically puts all numbers (including decimals) in an array... 
`$array = str_split( 'Gold 5.0mm Rolo Chain 18" In');
$concat = "";
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if(is_numeric($value) or $value == "."){
    $concat .= $value;
  } else {
    if(!empty($concat)){
      $numbers[] = $concat; // then add to an array
    }
    $concat = "";
  }
}`

Comment: @Werner I appreciate you effort but What do you say about this https://eval.in/779596

Comment: @SahilGulati Haha, nicely beautified... (I couldn't be bothered, it was just a side note... ) Thanks!

Comment: hi @SahilGulati if want to get '7 1/2' from string like 'Gold 5mm Bracelet 7 1/2" In' using preg_match before work of 'In' or '"'. can you please help me.

Comment: @RP Okay giving you regular expression

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5f83ce805518ffda7b291f96c79c11a42fff00c

Answer (score 0):

> want to `mm` number and `In` number from string.

I guess you can use:

```
preg_match_all('/[\d.]+/si', $s, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5.0
    [1] => 18
)
```

Comment: Thank @Pedro for reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Gold 5.0mm Rolo Chain 18" In"';

preg_match('/([\d\.]+)[m]{2}[A-z\ ]+([\d]+)[A-z\"\ ]+/',$string,$matches);

/**
* $match[1] - 5.0
* $match[2] - 18
*/
```

Comment: FYI `[A-z]` matches `[`, backslash, `]`, `^`, `_` and backtick